# Slime in emacs seems has conflicts with autopair

Tags: plugins, emacs, slime

I have just install slime in emacs. And after removed all the other plugins for debuging, I found that slime seems had conflicts with [autopair](https://code.google.com/p/autopair/).(Or a bug of autopair?).In slime, when I typed C-c C-c, the minibuffer displayed error like:

```
error in process filter: define-key: Wrong type argument: characterp, nil
error in process filter: Wrong type argument: characterp, nil
error in process filter: define-key: Wrong type argument: characterp, nil
error in process filter: Wrong type argument: characterp, nil
```

Even more, the error message still alerted after I killed the slime buffer.

If I also remove the autopair plugin, slime works just fine. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook
          #'(lambda () 
              (setq autopair-dont-activate t)))
```

to .emacs is the right answer. :)

From: [here](https://code.google.com/p/autopair/issues/detail?id=32)

Comment: For emacs >= 24 its (autopair-mode -1)